# Wifi driver not working after last Ubuntu 20.04 update

Tags: drivers, wireless, updates

Did last Ubuntu update changed something for Broadcom WiFi?
In September I had to disable "Secure boot" in BIOS to make it working. Now it does not work at all.

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b5500000-b5507fff
```

Comment: The last update could install the 5.8 kernel . As always the Canonical prople forgot to update `bcmwl-kernel-source`. Boot with a previous kernel.

Comment: See instructions on how to implement the recommendation from @Pilot6 (which, by the way, was the _precise_ issue I had, so--thanks) [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/82144/1103141). Pilot6, you should post that as a real answer so we can credit you.