# Latest 20.04 update problems

Tags: wireless, 20.04, updates, bluetooth

Monday 11 January I updated Ubuntu 20.04 with, I presume, the latest patch. I didn't look so closely, Ubuntu wanted to update and I just clicked the button. After restart, a number of peripherals stopped working:

- Wifi
- Bluetooth
- USB camera
- USB microphone

No problem with graphics or mouse/keyboard thankfully. But I'm not very familiar with Linux or Ubuntu yet, and would like to know:

1. Has anybody else experienced any problems with the latest update? I tried searching around, but haven't seen anything.
2. What are some initial steps to remedy this? I've searched for solutions, but they've seemed very specific to certain brands of equipment.

Comment: Review your /var/log/apt/history.log and /var/log/apt/term.log to see what upgrades actually occurred, and if you missed any warnings or errors. Different people get [different updates on different days](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates), so "*I updated on day X*" or "*the latest update*" is not specific enough. Also review your /var/log/syslog for error messages. Don't assume that an upgrade is responsible -- maybe it is, maybe it's not. Gather more data.

Comment: I had a problem with wifi after the latest kernel update. I saw a question asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1305593/1103141), and I found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version/82144#82144). Some of those issues will likely be patched quickly, though.

Comment: Probably kernel upgrade was not full. Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep linux` to your question.

Comment: Probably the kernel upgrade was not complete, but if the problem was caused by updating the kernel to the latest version then [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1306391/) explains how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Exact same problem in Xubuntu 20.04 running on Lenovo Thinkpad P53 running kernel 5.8.0-36-generic. I downgraded to 5.4.0-60 and everything works again.